# How to change width of an element without using media queries?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with a bunch of paragraphs, which look too stretched out on large screens. So I set width: 600px to p. Which made it look nice.

Only problem is that on small screens the paragraphs are still at 600px.

Any way to go around this without messing around with media queries?

In short I want .p to have width:600px; on large screens and no width setting on smaller than 600px.

Comment: what you are describing is a CSS media query. you dont need bootstrap though.

Comment: My apologies, I was under impression that it's Bootstrap thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use`max-width` like snippet below:

```css
div {
    width:100%;
    max-width:400px;
  }
```

```html
<div>I have a page with a bunch of paragraphs, which look too stretched out on large screens. So I set width: 600px to p. Which made it look nice.</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for exactly! 2 entries and it works like a peach. Thank you very much, sir. Question, is it possible to text-align:center if it's below 600px?

Comment: Max width for paragraphs (or any block of text) is best set using _ems_, which scale based on the font size. Lines that are too long in terms of _words_ (not pixels) are hard to read; professional typography advice is to [get 45–90 characters per line](http://practicaltypography.com/line-length.html), and chars-per-line scales with changes in point-size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery in this case.

```
if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
   $("p").css("width","400");
}
if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
   $("p").css("width","600");
}
```

You can change the numbers as your wish.

Edit: As mentioned on the comment above, you can just use the media queries without using the Bootstrap framework.

Comment: I am building the website on Bootstrap anyway, I just didn't want to spend a large chunk of my time setting up all the media queries for paragraphs. I am not familiar with jquery at all. Other than creating new .js file and linking it in the main page, do I have to do anything else?

Comment: To add on to this answer - if you're using JavaScript to calculate this you'll want to run the logic like Sandip wrote both on the load event, and likely also on the window resize event - that way it will work if the user resizes the browser after the page loads!

Answer (score 0):

It's no more effort to set up media queries than it is to use jQuery as @Sandip Subedi describes above. It's a matter of preference.

In your CSS you simply need:

```
p { width: 600px; }
@media (max-width < 600px) {
  p { width: 100%; }
}
```

That will set your p to a fixed 600px when the screen is greater than 600px wide, then the media query lets the p be 100% wide on anything smaller.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I should learn queries anyway, and it doesn't seem so bad. In regards to performance, do you know if there is any difference between doing this or jquery way?

Comment: @raimond using CSS media queries for this will perform far better than any JavaScript-based solution for this! Thankfully CSS media queries have a pretty small learning curve, the best way to learn them is to write a bunch and experiment with what they do :)

Comment: Yep, @innovati beat me to it :). CSS is far lighter and much more performant than a jQuery solution. Check out Using Media Queries on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries for more info.